# Using FLM file in MDK (Keil Uvision) to flash external SPI FLASH via JLink

Tags: arm, segger-jlink

**Target and toolchain context**

So i use an exotic Cortex M4 device with NPU (2 core m4, 1 core NPU).
This SoC has a small internal flash and SRAM, and an external 16MB SPI FLASH and 8 MB SDRAM.
The firmware is essentially either flashed on SPI FLASH for production, or SDRAM for development. internal FLASH is only used for BOOT1 essentially.

**The issue**

I try to flash the firmware to external SPI FLASH from MDK.

**What has been tried**

So the toolchain includes an MDK template already set with the FLM file for SDRAM operations, i use this template for the development / debug. A standalone tool to flash the SPI FLASH partitions is also provided, be it for boot1, firmware or the other data partitions. This tool is fine for production, but not convenient during development.
I also have an FLM file for the external SPI FLASH, this file contains the flash algorithm that is needed by MDK to flash the SPI FLASH, unfortunetely, no MDK template is provided to use it, so i am unsure of the exact configuration of the MDK project to acheive flashing firmware to external SPI FLASH.

Here is the memory map of this SoC

flash address space
code run from flash (0x10000000)
data run from sram (0x20000000)

sdram address space
code run from sdram (0xC0000000+ReserveSize(64K))
data run from sdram (code address + codeImageSize)

sram address space
code run from sram (0x20000000)
data run from sram (code address + codeImageSize)

and here is the project options for the current configuration with SDRAM.

[MDK option/target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2Cjv.png)

[MDK target/Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTAv2.png)

[MDK Jlink Flash Download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/no0Ng.png)

I added a new configuration for EXT_FLASH

[MDK Jlink Flash Download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyiYc.png)

Here are the fields i am not sure about

[MDK Jlink Flash Download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYIrJ.png)

[MDK options/target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHWpe.png)

Does anyone know what is wrong in my setup?